# What is Application of Vector Algebra in Economics?

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, mathematical-economics

I through one tutors heard that vector is used in economics .
But on searching about it on internet could not find anything

Recently I studied about Vectors in Mathematics

So I was wondering how could Vector be used in Economics ?

Comment: How about in [a multivariate ordinary least squares estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Matrix/vector_formulation) and [the first welfare theorem of economics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorems_of_welfare_economics#Proof_of_the_First_Theorem)?